# Variable declared inside try block can't be resolved

Tags: java, exception

Just learning exception catching. This produces "height cannot be resolved to a variable". I guess I'm missing something crucial.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Step4_lab01 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner userIn = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Input height: ");
        try {
            int height = userIn.nextInt();
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e)
        {
            System.out.println("ERORRORrr");
        }
        System.out.print("Input width: ");
        int width = userIn.nextInt();

        Rectangle rektangel1 = new Rectangle(height,width);
        rektangel1.computeArea();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you better change your code to :

```
int height = 0;
int width  = 0;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

while(true){
 try{
   height = scanner.nextInt();
   break;
  }catch(InputMismatchException ex){
   System.out.println("Height must be in numeric, try again!");
   scanner.next();
   /*
    * nextInt() read an integer then goes to next line,what if the input was not
    * numeric, then it goes to catch, after catch it goes back to try, then reads
    * an empty line which is also not numeric, that caused the infinity loop.
    * next() will read this empty line first, then nextInt() reads the integer value.
    * The problem have been solved.
   /*
  }
}
```

Do this also for the width, the thing you didn't expect from your code is the *height* inside the try block, you must note that it's *vailed* only inside *try* block. Whenever you go outside, you don't have access to it. 

Another thing, don't ever forget the message inside catch block, it's strongly recommended to have a meaningful message, if not, then `printStackTrace()` will be great.

Comment: Good idea! Code doesn't work for me though. I get trapped in an infinite "Height must be in numeric, try again!" loop.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the variable 'height' outside the try block so as to be visible outside the block.